# Accessing WinForms Controls from a serial port in a class

Tags: c#, serial-port

First, the apology: I'm new to posting questions on this site, so I apologize for formatting or information errors.I have seen many answers to taking data from a serial port dropped on a form and using it to populate text boxes, graphs, etc. on the main form, using "Invoke" because the serial port is running in a different thread.

I am trying to "generalize" some comm stuff we use all the time in to a class (yes, the old VB6 programmer is trying to grow up :-) and I'm having issues. I can do some things if I force a form name in the main program.cs and use the same namespace for the class, but this sorta defeats the purpose. I've also tried adding an event on the "received" even of the serial port in the class to raise an event on the main form. The event tries to get raised but a cross thread exception occurs.

The code at this point is quite large, so I'll  try to "outline" it. In simplistic form, assuming I have a for called "Form1" which contains a text box called textbox1 and a class called "SerialThing":

---

## Form1:

```
SerialThing mySerialThing ;
```

### Form1_Load:

```
mySerialThing = new SerialThing();
```

### DisplayData()

```
Textbox1.Text = "You Got Data!";
```

---

## SerialThing:

```
Static SerialPort myDevice;
```

### Init()

```
myDevice = new SerialPort;
myDevice.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(devicePort_DataReceived);
```

### devicePort_DataReceived()

```
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayData));
```

---

The above will work if the serial port is placed on the main form, but not if created inside the class.

Again, sorry if too complex, or too simplistic. I am looking for an "easy" way to do this, but keep the class "generalized" (ideally not have to have the workspace names match, etc).

-Vin

Comment: Well, *this.Invoke()* isn't going to work very well if *this* is a class instead of the Form object.  Your class doesn't have an Invoke method.  Use an event instead so the form class can still call this.Invoke() in its event handler to take care of the required marshaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this.  I'll present the classic approach using a custom event, delegates, and Invoke(), as I think it's important to understand that process.  Once you've got this down, you can jump to some of the newer approaches.

First, in your SerialThing() class, you declare a Custom event to pass out data when it is received:

```
class SerialThing
{

    public delegate void DataReceivedDelegate(string data);
    public event DataReceivedDelegate DataReceived;

    static SerialPort myDevice;

    public SerialThing()
    {
        myDevice = new SerialPort();
        myDevice.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(myDevice_DataReceived);
    }

    void myDevice_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... grab the data and place into a string called "data" ...
        string data = "";

        // raise our custom event:
        if (DataReceived != null)
        {
            DataReceived(data);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, over in Form1, you subscribe to that custom event when you create the instance of SerialThing.  Additionally, when that event is received, you marshal the call from the secondary thread to the main thread using InvokeRequired, Invoke, and a delegate:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SerialThing mySerialThing;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mySerialThing = new SerialThing();
        mySerialThing.DataReceived += new SerialThing.DataReceivedDelegate(mySerialThing_DataReceived);
    }

    private delegate void DataReceivedDelegate(string data);

    void mySerialThing_DataReceived(string data)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new DataReceivedDelegate(mySerialThing_DataReceived), new Object[] { data });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = data;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: In response to your comments below...

Think of a delegate as simply a "pointer to a method".  When you execute the delegate, the associated method gets run.

The InvokeRequired() portion determines if the code is running in a different thread than the one that created the control.  In this case, the control is the Form itself (`this`).  If true is returned, then the event was received in a different thread.  We then proceed to `this.Invoke()` line inside the true portion of the `If` block.  Again `this` refers to the Form.  Thus the Form is requesting to Invoke ("run") the passed delegate on the thread that created it (the main UI thread).  We create a instance of the delegate that actually points to the same method we are already in resulting in a recursive call.  The second parameter is simply an array of Object used to pass the parameters along with the delegate.

When Invoke() is run we end up re-entering the method because of the recursive call.  At this point, however, the InvokeRequired() check will return false as we are now running in the main UI thread.  Therefore we drop down into the false portion of the `If` statement where we update the TextBox.  In this pattern it is safe to update an GUI controls in the `else` block of the `If` statement.

Note that a recursive call isn't necessary here.  This is simply a style choice.  We could have instead used a second "helper" function that the delegate pointed to, and Invoked that instead.  The recursive approach reduces the number of methods required.

This is perhaps the most verbose approach to solving this type of problem.  I like it, though, as it shows the flow of events and data, and movement between the threads.

We could shorten all the Form code to just this, using anonymous delegates:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mySerialThing = new SerialThing();
        mySerialThing.DataReceived += delegate (string data)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() { textBox1.Text = data; }));
        };
    }
```

I don't know about you, but as a former VB6 programmer myself, that just looks weird when you first see that type of thing.

> I've also used components that I know have things running in different
>   threads, yet the "form code" has never had to use the delegate stuff,
>   so maybe there's something that can be buried into the class?

Yes, it's possible to bake some "magic" into a class so that it raises events already on the main UI thread, thus not requiring any Invoke() calls.  One way to do this is thru using a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

Another possibility for approaching this type of problem would be to use a BackgroundWorker() control which has events such as ProgressChanged() and RunWorkerCompleted() that are raised in the main UI thread for you (they do the necessary invoking type stuff under the hood for you).

Comment: Thank you for all the above. I pieced it into my existing code at home last night, following the example, and was able to test it here in the office today. It works perfectly! Thanks!! Now I suppose I need to read up about delegates because I'm not sure exactly HOW or WHY it works, and why just the event does not. I've also used components that I know have things running in different threads, yet the "form code" has never had to use the delegate stuff, so maybe there's something that can be buried into the class?

Comment: Also, You mentioned this a good "base knowledge" but there are other ways. Is there a good reference for looking at the different ways and comparing/contrasting them? Thanks again for the thorough help!

Comment: (Based on EDIT) 
Wow! That's a great explanation. Thanks so much. Yes, I do prefer to see the flow myself. I am mostly an embedded designer (small micros, 8-32 bit) hardware and firmware (in C). My desktop experience has been in designing "front-ends" to embedded systems: calibration, data upload, etc.) and would not be the person one would come to for designing an enterprise system (although we get more and more requests to post live data to a website these days). I picked VB6 15 years ago and switched to C# about 3 years ago. I do mostly serial comm to the embedded system.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to see someone following the same trend as myself. Being an embedded programmer, the higher level ideas such as delegates and events I simply never understood. The only reason I do PC coding is for a serial port app or programmer app for my embedded code :)